# C float reset to 0 after passing it to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

In the code below,the variable "tmpRes" is correct before the call of "BuildCMD"
but inside this function,it loose his correct value and sets to 0,why it just doesn't keep the correct value even inside the BuildCMD function?

Calling code:

```
//tmpRead just an array of integer
float tmpRes=0;
Evaluate(tmpRead[3],tmpRead[4],tmpRead[5],&tmpRes);
printf("PRE : %f\n",tmpRes);   //correct result
char *dataBuff=BuildCMD(RES,tmpData,tmpRes);
```

Evaluate code:

```
int Evaluate(int num1,int op,int num2,float *Res)
{
     float tmpRes=0;
     switch(op)
     {
           case(int)'+':{tmpRes=num1+num2;break;} //same with *Res=....
           case(int)'-':{tmpRes=num1-num2;break;}
           //etc...
     }
    *Res=tmpRes;
    return 0;
```

}

BuildCMD:

```
char* BuildCMD(enum CMD cmd,int *values,float result)
{
     //here the result is ALWAYS 0
     //even if it was corrent before the call of BuildCMD
     printf("IN: %f\n,result);   
     fflush(stdout);
     //...rest of the code
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Yes,the application is multi threaded,i create n instances of mainClient from the server.
Links to the sourcecode (the one i wrote above is simplified).
[mainClient.c](http://tny.cz/497e30b5)
[Utilities.c](http://tny.cz/e14ee3ec)

Comment: Are there prototypes for the `BuildCMD()` and `Evaluate()` functions that are included before the calling code calls them?

Comment: We need to see more code.

Comment: Oh right,the calling code and the two function are in two different files.The calling code is in "main.c" while "BuildCMD" and "Evaluate" are in "Utilities.c",but since they see each other in the code i didn't include anything except for "Data.h" that has the CMD enum inside.
Ps:i'm going to post the full code in tynipaste,give me a minute.

Comment: is this single threaded or multi threaded?

Comment: printf quotes are not closed correctly in BuildCMD

Comment: @user1526262: main needs to know what types to pass, by default, it would be assuming an `int`, is the `tmpRes` value close to zero perhaps? You should have got a compiler warning about that.

Comment: @user1526262 i guess the result is initialized to the first field in the enum datatype hence printing zero.can you show the complete code .

Comment: Try to compile it with a C standard compiler, such as `gcc -std=c99`. It would have found these problems for you, which is one of many reasons why using non-standard compilers is a bad idea.

Comment: @Ludin thanks for the tip on the compiling options,now it gives me the declaration warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the code that calls BuildCMD does not have a proper prototype for that function.

You need this prototype either in main.c or in a .h file that main.c includes:

```
char* BuildCMD(enum CMD cmd,int *values,float result);
```

Comment: Yeeeah thanks a lot!
I declared BuildCMD and Evaluate in mainClient.c file as you said and now it works just fine,thanks!

Comment: It resolve a bug for me too. Never compile without -Werror again!

Answer (score 0):

You have `float tmpRes=0;` inside `Evaluate()`. So in fact the `Evaluate()` doesn't use the global `tmpRes`. The global `tmpRes` remain `0` even though you pass it into `Evaluate()`.

Comment: `tmpRes` is passed by pointer and called `Res`, which is updated correctly.